# Mac's Android File Explorer and SSH are not in sync

Tags: sync, photos, ssh, media-scanner

I transfered some photos using the Android File Explorer application for Macs.

However, I accidentally put them in the Music/ folder and Android File Explorer doesn't allow me to move files. So I decide to SSH into my Nexus 4 and move the photos into the Pictures/ folder via the `mv` command. This went great - everything was moved successfully according to `ls`.

Unfortunately, when I go to Gallery, it doesn't detect the photos. Worse yet, every time I start up Android File Explorer, it isn't updated with the new location of the photos, they still show up in the Music/ folder.

I'm running Jellybean 4.2.2 on a Nexus 4, connected to a Macbook Pro via Android File Explorer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try rebooting, works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using an app that runs the MediaIndexer.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.addz.mediascanner&hl=en

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clypher.mediascanner

Rebooting works as well, thanks user133312!